# Why is ‘die Informationen’ used instead of just ‘die Information’ in German?

Tags: grammatical-number

In reading German newspapers, I keep on encountering instances, when *die Information* is used in its plural form, *die Informationen*. The most recent example is this sentence from *[Süddeutsche Zeitung](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/vw-abgas-affaere-regierung-wusste-seit-jahren-von-manipulationen-1.3138240)*:

> In der Abgas-Affäre um weit überhöhte Schadstoffwerte bei Diesel-Fahrzeugen gehen nach **Informationen** von *Süddeutscher Zeitung*, NDR und WDR mehrere vom Bundestag zu Rate gezogene Experten hart mit der Autobranche und der Politik ins Gericht.

[Dict.cc](http://de-en.dict.cc/?s=Informationen) provides further examples of using *die Information* in its plural form:

> Informationen austauschen = to share information
>
> Informationen bekommen = to obtain information
>
> Informationen einholen = to gather information

So, why is *die Informationen* used in all of the above examples? Would it be wrong to use the singular version of the noun in the above examples?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your examples use the plural because it's more than a single piece of information.

In English, information exists only in singular, in German there is a valid plural --- Informationen. Using the plural is much more common cause mostly you are dealing with more than just a single bit of information. I wouldn't say it is completely wrong to just use the singular in German, but it sounds odd to me.

The notable exception is the desk with the big i sign: an information desk is referred to as "die Information" in German.

Comment: Two unrelated information desks would be "die Informationen" - for example "Die Informationen in beiden Hotels waren ganz ausgezeichnet". Quite rarely used.